# C++ enhanced cat

Tags: c++, string, input, user-input

Suppose I have a function from string to string, such as for example:

```
string identity(string text) {
    return text;
}
```

How can I print the function applied to input to output, avoiding explicit variables, input and output handling? Something like `interact` in Haskell.

```
int main() {
    std::interact(identity);
}
```

This would really cut down obvious code, and let the algoritmh and the logic stand out instead.

Example usage would be:

```
$./enhanced_cat
Example
Example
$
```

Comment: How much input at a time should be passed to the function?

Comment: @aschepler One line, until the user hits enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily write such a thing yourself using `std::function`. Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::string identity(std::string const& text) {
    return text;
}

void interact(std::function<std::string(std::string const&)> f)
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::cout << f(input);
}

int main()
{
    interact(identity);
}
```

But that certainly doesn't look like idiomatic C++. Even though C++ supports functional programming to a certain extent, it's not a functional programming language, and you should not try to write Haskell in C++.

Comment: Next you'll say you shouldn't write python in C++.  Stealing other languages cool stuff is idiomatic C++!  The entire language started as stealing OO and adding it to C.  Why stop?

Comment: @Yakk: *"Aim to write idiomatic C++: avoid simply writing code in the style of your previous language using C++ syntax; there is little to be gained from simply changing syntax."* -- Bjarne Stroustrup [http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#how-to-start]

Comment: sure, that is a good way to start learning C++ (if you stick with the old language's patterns, you are going to be stuck doing the intersection of what the two languages can do).  But once you know C++, mugging other languages is a great way to get better at it.  Some of my prettiest code comes from language-mugging.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class F>
struct interacter_t {
  F f;
  void operator()( std::istream& is = std::cin, std::ostream& os = std::cout ) {
    std::string in;
    while( getline( is, in ) ) {
      os << f(std::move(in)) << '\n';
    }
  }
};
template<class F>
interacter_t<std::decay_t<F>> interact( F&& f ) {
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

then:

```
int main() {
  auto io = interact(identity);
  std::cout << "Start:\n";
  io();
  std::cout << "End.\n";
}
```

I added the separate invocation to creation of the interactor object.

You can do it on one line:

```
  std::cout << "Start:\n";
  interact(identity)();
  std::cout << "End.\n";
```

or you can modify `interact` to run the `interactor_t` instead of returning it.  I personally like that distinction: creation and execution are different things.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5dc7869ccf925664).

This version reads everything from the input stream until it ends.  Reading less than that is easy, just replace the body of `operator()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could roll your own interact, something like the below. (Note: probably won't actually compile as is.)

```
void interact(string (*function)(string))
{
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << function(input) << endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::function` would be more general than a function pointer.